# Get the most repeated post contents from a search?

Tags: php, html

In my site the posts content is always the name of a school, so if I search for Chicago I get a lot of posts with different schools as content. What I want to do is to get the Schools with the most posts, so I could display this somewhere:

```
School A - 4
School B - 3
School C - 2
School D - 2
```

(The number at the right is the number of posts the school has)

So what I need to get the most repeated post contents from a particular search including the ones that don't appear in first results page.

I don't know how complicated it can be so if there is no simple way I would be very grateful for just being pointed towards the right direction, so I later figure out how to do it. My site is made with wordpress and the posts are on a SQL database. Please ask if it's not clear or for any more info.

Thanks

Comment: Is this information in a database of some sort?

Comment: And if it is, can you post the relevant part of the schema?

Comment: Where is the schema? I'll post it but I haven o idea what part of the code it is. =S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that these posts are stored in some SQL database? If so you can get the database to do the work:

```
SELECT school, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM posts
GROUP BY school
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: Assuming this is the way your database is set up, this sounds like a very simple approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's stored on a SQL database. I'm very new to web design. This could be a stupid question but how do I add that to my code? Thanks a lot though if that code works I'll save a lot of trouble

Comment: Well give us a snippet or something that we can work with. The one that handles that part of your website.

Comment: Ok, is it useful if I add the form with which people adds posts? I never ever touched the SQL database since it was created. Just tell me what info could help and where to find it and I'll post it right away. Thanks

Comment: @Liso22: I think ou would benefit greatly from either a) learning PHP from a tutorial, or b) hiring a programmer to make this change for you. It's very unlikely you will be able to make the change correctly if you have no experience with PHP and it's difficult for us to help you if you don't even know where the code is that needs modifying.

Comment: Do I need to change something? I just wanted to display it somewhere on the results page. I understand, I'm sorry if I can give little help. I'll get somebody to do it for me as you suggested. Thanks anyway